# Wikipedia viewer results duplicating after searching for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, wikipedia-api

I am trying to build a wiki viewer and ran into a little problem.

I am using wikipedia api. After typing in search input user is presented with 5 possible articles(title and first sentence of the article) and after clicking on them they should be redirected to wikipedia page and see the article in full.

After searching for second time(puting in new word) I am running into a problem. There are empty divs on the bottom of the page and whenever user tries to click on the desired article for further reading there are two wikipedia pages open.

Any suggestions?

```
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&datatype=json&limit=5&search=' + inputVal + '&callback=?', function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) { 
                    $('<div class="item"><h4></h4><p></p></div>').appendTo(".search-area");
                    $('h4').eq(i).text(data[1][i]);
                    $('p').eq(i).text(data[2][i]);
                };
                $('.item').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var wikiLoc = $(this).find('h4').text();
                    window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + wikiLoc);
                });
```

Here is full code: http://codepen.io/nikasv/pen/pbzrzj

Comment: The click events stay bound to the .item elements. you need to either fully remove the elements and recreate them or remove the bindings with $.off()

Answer (score 1):

you can add add

```
$(".item").remove();
```

in line 3 to remove all previous results

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
            $(".item").remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            var inputVal = $('input').val();
    ....
```

http://codepen.io/Crazy/pen/VjZzjG/

Answer (score 0):

Before for loop add `$(".search-area").empty()`